# Bright background in termcap

Tags: terminal, termcap

I'm trying to get a program I'm running to display a bright colored background, but the program won't apply the brightness increase, it instead shows a 'normal' colored background.

Let me add some details:

- I log into a server running Debian, through PuTTY, with the `TERM` variable set to `putty` (or manually do this using `export TERM=putty`).
- I first try whether bright backgrounds show up correctly at all, using

  ```
  echo -e "\e[43mHello\e[0m \e[103mWorld\e[0m"
  ```

  You see that `\e[43m` is the code for setting the background to yellow and `\e[103m` is the code for setting the background color to bright yellow. The image below shows that it actually works:

  [image: Both normal and bright yellow background work]
- Then I run the program I want to display such bright backgrounds. The program is the ACUCOBOL runtime. The manual says that it tries to read the `TERM` value and reads `/etc/a_termcap` by this value, selecting the (hopefully) proper terminal capabilities, if used on a *nix OS. The Windows client doesn't use any terminal capability info.

  The entry within the `a_termcap` file looks like this:

  ```
  putty|/PuTTY Colors:\
      :k1=\E[[A:k2=\E[[B:k3=\E[[C:k4=\E[[D:k5=\E[[E:k6=\E[17~:k7=\E[18~:\
      :k8=\E[19~:k9=\E[20~:k0=\E[21~:K1=\E[23~:K2=\E[24~:\
      :KE=\E[4~:KI=\E[2~:ku=\E[A:kd=\E[B:kl=\E[D:kr=\E[C:\
      :kh=\E[1~:al=\E[L:dl=\E[M:KX=\E[3~:li#25:DI=\E[m:kN=\E[G:kP=\E[I:\
      :cl=\E[;H\E[J:cm=\E[%i%d;%dH:ce=\E[K:cd=\E[J:DL:nd=\E[C:\
      :RV=\E[7m:HI=\E[0;1m:LO=\E[m:BL=\E[5m:UL=\E[4m:RB=\E[5;7m:RU=\E[4;7m:\
      :C1=\E[30m:C2=\E[34m:C3=\E[32m:C4=\E[36m:C5=\E[31m:C6=\E[35m:\
      :C7=\E[33m:C8=\E[37m:AC:\
      :B1=\E[40m:B2=\E[44m:B3=\E[42m:B4=\E[46m:B5=\E[41m:B6=\E[45m:\
      :B7=\E[43m:B8=\E[47m:UL@:RU@:\
      :GO=\016:GF=\017:\
      :GM=\161\170\154\153\155\152\166\164\167\165\156:
  ```

  The problem is that I can barely read these values, but the codes `C1` … `C8` and `B1` … `B8` refer to the foreground and background colors respectively, I think.

My guess is that the runtime is not aware of the codes `\e[100m` … `\e[107m`. How can I fix this?

---

#### Edit

It seems that I can somehow *can* get black and white to be bright. Below a screenshot which allows both the bright and normal variants of black and white.

[image: black and white bright]

---

#### Edit

I have changed the terminal emulator name to `putty` and set the `TERM` variable accordingly. I don't think, however, that it matters.

Comment: The image is not from Linux's built-in terminal emulator, which does not produce the effect claimed in response to those control sequences.  That is some other terminal emulator, not the Linux built-in one.

Comment: Linux's built-in terminal emulator does not have scroll bars, either.  Are you going to tell us what terminal emulator you are _actually_ using?

Comment: It doesn't matter - almost all of the available terminal emulators copied xterm's behavior.  The actual question is whether ACUCOBOL can manage more than 8 colors (it cannot).

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: By the way, I'm using the PuTTY client. `putty` was not a valid entry within the `a_termcap` file, so I changed it to something the ACUCOBOL runtime would even understand.

Comment: That was wrong, note.  The `linux` terminal type does not describe PuTTY, and the very first sentence of the ACUCOBOL doco explains that the right thing to do is set up an entry describing PuTTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short: you can't

long: The [ACUCOBOL](https://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/AcucorpProducts/docs/v6_online_doc/runtime/run220.htm) support page explains what the termcap fields are.  It knows about **8** colors, while your example expects to use the [aixterm 16-color controls](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html).  Handling all 16 colors is beyond the ability of a termcap application (unless it cheats and formats its own strings rather than using `tgoto`).

You could make all of the backgrounds use bright colors, but you can't make some scenarios bright and some not.   The places to modify would be `B1` to `B8` (colors 0-7 in the usual numbering convention):

```
:B1=\E[40m:B2=\E[44m:B3=\E[42m:B4=\E[46m:B5=\E[41m:B6=\E[45m:\
:B7=\E[43m:B8=\E[47m:
```

replacing 40 by 100, 41 by 101, etc.

By the way, `TERM=linux` is inconsistent with the example of an escape sequence which you gave (since Linux console's 16 colors are achieved by combining **bold** with colors 0-7, i.e., replacing **`40`** by **`40;1`**, etc).  You could copy that entry and change the name in the first line

```
linux|/Linux system console:\
```

to something more suitable, e.g.,

```
putty|bright-backgrounds:\
```

A termcap description cannot produce values in two ranges (40-47, 100-107 for example) since it doesn't support *expressions*.  A terminfo description (not supported by ACUCOBOL, apparently) can do this.  For example, ncurses has a [16-color Linux](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux-16color) description.  There are similar descriptions for other terminals, including whatever terminal you are actually using.

Comment: [The _GT Users' Guide_](https://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/acucorpproducts/docs/v6_online_doc/gtman1/gt1431.htm) has a more complete description than the _Runtime Manual_.

Comment: Its documentation of color is no better.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it (now) makes sense to me. Leaves me with one last question (see question edit): why can the brightness still be applied to black and white? That should be impossible, isn't it?

Comment: It looks like you ran a script which sent codes 100-107.  You can modify a termcap to do that, but can't make it choose from both 40-47 and 100-107.

Comment: Its documentation of colour _gives the answer_.  It is not actually "you can't", and it's one of several reasons that correctly stating the output device in the question is important.

Comment: @ThomasDickey That's what it makes peculiar — the colored picture in my question is actually generated by the ACUCOBOL runtime.

Comment: Sure - it could be using some combination not apparent in the termcap - but if you want to know what escape sequences it's actually using, you could use **`script`** to capture that (and perhaps use `cat -v` to render the result readable).